# Domain, subdomain and path forwarding

Tags: domains, redirects, dns, subdomain, domain-forwarding

I have four domains:

```
domain.in
domain.com
domain.org
domain.co.in
```

I want to make `domain.in` as my main domain. I want to forward all my other domains to it. I want to set up forwarding such that:

1. `domain.com` goes to `domain.in`
2. `www.domain.com` goes to `www.domain.in`
3. `xyz.domain.com` goes to `xyz.domain.in`
4. `abc.domain.com/path/to/directory` goes to `abc.domain.in/path/to/directory`

How can I do that?

[Screenshot of my registrar's domain forwarding form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb8j4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do that with the options that your registrar give you.  You will have to point your domains to your web host (probably with [wildcard DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record)) and do it yourself.

Here is a rewrite rule that you can put in your `.htaccess` file that will redirect any subdomain and path of `domain.com`, `domain.org`, or `domain.co.in` to the corresponding subdomain and path of `domain.in`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)domain\.(com|org|(co\.in))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1domain.in/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, Stephen!
Do you know of any registrar which provides these options? It looks like a very obvious feature to me (for example to redirect misspelled domains etc.)

Comment: Registrars typically only off the simplest redirect options.  Implement this off of the registrar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.theothersite.com">
```

If you don't fancy rewriting anything, just pop that into a web-page and Bob's your uncle.